# How to set Start and end time in Jmeter Scheduler as variables

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to load test my app by setting the Start and end time in Scheduler as a variables eg:

```
Start Time : ${START_TIME}
End Time : ${END_TIME}
```

bit Jmeter is not allowing to save it.Is it not a configurable option ?

This is what I want to do

```
jmeter -Jduration=600 -n -t /path/to/your/test/plan.jmx
```

This will kick of the tests immediately for 10 mins (600s)
Can the start time be configured in such a way that it is always a current time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure it but it has to be a valid [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

If you want to control duration of your test I would recommend the following:

1. Test `Start Time` can be set by OS means (cron jobs, scheduled tasks, continuous integration system build plan, etc.)
2. Test `Duration` can be set via JMeter Property.

For instance, you want your test to run for 2 hours. In order to achieve this you need to provide the value of "7200" into "Duration" section of thread group. If you put `${__property(duration,,)}` or `${__P(duration,)}` into "Duration" input of thread group and set this `duration=7200` property in i.e. `user.properties` or `jmeter.properties` files (they both live under /bin folder of your JMeter installation) or provide it as a command-line argument as

```
jmeter -Jduration=7200 -n -t /path/to/your/test/plan.jmx -l /path/to/results/file.jtl
```

The test will run for 2 hours (plus some additional time to gracefully shut down all the test threads).

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more details on JMeter Properties use cases.

Comment: that is exactly what I want.One question though - How can I achieve Step 1 of the above recommendation.To be precise :
"Test Start Time can be set by OS means (cron jobs, scheduled tasks, continuous integration system build plan, etc.)"

Comment: It depends on what operating system or CI system you use and how do you kick off your JMeter tests.

Comment: The Operating system being used is Linux.My question is not related to OS driven values.It is more specific to how am I am going to execute my tests.I have updated the question to include what I want

Comment: "Start time" will always be current time. You can look into `at` or `crontab -e` or shell script in loop or whatever. Test will start at the time you invoke your `jmeter.sh` startup script and will last for what you specify as `duration` property.